# JQuery Find Elements By Background-Color

Tags: jquery

Trying to access the Selected row of a GridView by using JQuery to find the row with the background-color attribute set to the SelectedRowStyle background color. That color is #FF6600. I've tried

```
var row = $("tr").find().css("background-color", "#FF6600");
```

But that just sets all the rows to orange.

```
var row = $("tr[background-color=#FF6600");
```

That returns empty

```
var row = $("tr").find().attr("background-color");
```

Returns undefined

Comment: Note: `.find()` returns an empty set.  Also `.css("background-color", "#FF6600")` sets the CSS property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
var rows = $('tr').filter(function(){
    var color = $(this).css("background-color");
    return color === "#FF6600" || color === "rgb(255, 102, 0)" ;
});
```

I haven't tested it, the rgb part may need to be adjusted to account for spacing.

Edit:

or better yet, this takes into account uppercase vs lowercase

```
var rows = $('tr').filter(function(){
    var color = $(this).css("background-color").toLowerCase();
    return color === "#ff6600" || color === "rgb(255, 102, 0)" ;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

`background-color` is not an attribute, it's a CSS property.  You can try using `.filter` to do this:

```
var row = $("tr").filter(function(){
    // Chrome returns "rgb(255, 102, 0)" instead of "#FF6600"
    return $(this).css('background-color') === "rgb(255, 102, 0)";
});
```

Comment: Still returning a length of 0.

Comment: @jmease: `console.log($(this).css('background-color'))`.  Some browsers may output something different.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('background-color') == '#ff6600'){
         //do your stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this pseudo jQuery selector in my code, defined in utility file:

```js
(function() {
  function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    return '#' + rgb.match(/^rgb\(([^\)]+)\)$/)[1].split(/\s*,\s*/)
      .filter(Boolean).map(function(n) {
         return ('00' + parseInt(n, 10).toString(16)).slice(-2);
      }).join('');
  }
  $.extend($.expr[':'], {
  // pesudo selector that allow to use :css(color: red)
    css: function(element, index, meta) {
      element = $(element);
      var rules = meta[3].split(';').filter(Boolean);
      return rules.filter(function(pair) {
        pair = pair.split(/\s*:\s*/);
        var css = element.css(pair[0]);
        if (css.match(/rgb\(/)) {
          css = rgb2hex(css);
        }
        return css === pair[1];
      }).length === rules.length;
    }
  });
})();
$(function() {
  $('li:css(color: #ff0000)').css('background', 'black');
});
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="red">1</li>
<li style="color: red">2</li>
<li style="color: blue">3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

If you need to select element with `li:css(color: red)` to select red nodes, in Chrome the value red is converted to `rgb(255, 0, 0)`, so you need to convert red to the same value, to do that you can create dummy element that is inserted to body (it can have `visibility: hidden`)

```
var tmp = $('<span/>').css('visibility', 'hidden').appendTo('body');
```

element can be inserted once, and use:

```
tmp.css(pair[0], pair[1]);
//or
tmp.css.apply(tmp, pair);
// and
return tmp.css(pair[0]) == element.css(pair[0]);
```

```js
(function() {
  var tmp = $('<span/>').css('visibility', 'hidden').appendTo('body');
  $.extend($.expr[':'], {
  // pesudo selector that allow to use :css(color: red)
    css: function(element, index, meta) {
      element = $(element);
      var rules = meta[3].split(';').filter(Boolean);
      return rules.filter(function(pair) {
        pair = pair.split(/\s*:\s*/);
        tmp.css.apply(tmp, pair);
        return tmp.css(pair[0]) == element.css(pair[0]);
      }).length === rules.length;
    }
  });
})();
$(function() {
  $('li:css(color: red)').css('background', 'black');
});
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="red">1</li>
<li style="color: red">2</li>
<li style="color: blue">3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('tr').toArray().filter(f => f.style.backgroundColor == '#FF6600')
```